# How to generate insertAfter partial response in render response phase in jsf

Tags: jsf

In JSF How to generate `insertAfter` response in render renderresponse Phase.

I am able to generate `insertAfter` response in invokeapplication phase. But the problem is in response its generating two partial responses which is not a valid xml

```
FacesContext ctx=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
if(ctx.getPartialViewContext().isPartialRequest()) {
    PartialResponseWriter ps=ctx.getPartialViewContext().getPartialResponseWriter();
    ps.startDocument();
    ps.startInsertAfter("test");
    ps.startElement("div", null);
    ps.endElement("div");
    ps.endInsert();
    ps.endDocument();
}
```

It gives response as

```
<partial-response><changes><insert><after id="test"><![CDATA[<div></div>]]></after></insert></changes></partial-response><partial-response><changes><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[-8992354986067826873:-4155638239771809631]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

How can i make complete response in one partial response block so that it will be parsable.

Comment: I'll try to wrinte something up over the weekend, not a real answer but some information that is too much and needs too much formatting for a comment. Imo it boils down to this not really ever bing supported. But please add you JSF implementation and version to the question

Comment: @Kukeltje I am using jakarta 2.3.9

Comment: So you mean mojarra..

Comment: Yes i am using mojarra